# Micronaut's Framework with error `Path Taken`

Tags: micronaut

I am trying to create a scheduler as the guide from [this link](https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-scheduled/guide/index.html).

I am stuck and getting this error.

```
Message: org/springframework/core/log/LogDelegateFactory
Path Taken: new TransactionCheckerJob([Oauth2Template oauth2Template])
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [bank.transaction.service.scheduler.TransactionCheckerJob]

Message: org/springframework/core/log/LogDelegateFactory
Path Taken: new TransactionCheckerJob([Oauth2Template oauth2Template])
```

I don't know what went wrong here.

Here my source code at [GITHUB](https://github.com/gryphonest/bankauthtest)

I am using micronaut 1.0.3

Comment: There are currently 2 votes to close this question based on the claim that it is off topic.  I do not agree with that.  I think this question is about a programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the relevant part of the error message.  When I run your app I see the following:

```
Message: org/springframework/core/log/LogDelegateFactory
Path Taken: new TransactionCheckerJob([Oauth2Template oauth2Template])
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [bank.transaction.service.scheduler.TransactionCheckerJob]

Message: org/springframework/core/log/LogDelegateFactory
Path Taken: new TransactionCheckerJob([Oauth2Template oauth2Template])
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1345)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:1914)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:1635)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:1615)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:896)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:973)
        at bank.transaction.service.scheduler.$TransactionCheckerJobDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1331)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:1914)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanForDefinition(DefaultBeanContext.java:1635)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:1615)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:507)
        at io.micronaut.scheduling.processor.ScheduledMethodProcessor.lambda$process$5(ScheduledMethodProcessor.java:109)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/log/LogDelegateFactory
        at org.springframework.http.HttpLogging.forLog(HttpLogging.java:68)
        at org.springframework.http.HttpLogging.forLogName(HttpLogging.java:57)
...
```

That `NoClassDefFoundError` is the issue.  That error will go away if you add a dependency on `spring-core`.

Comment: Note that the Spring stuff isn't needed by Micronauts scheduler support.  Your application code is what needs the Spring classes.